# What is the difference between AWS Serverless Java and AWS Lambda Java Projects?

Tags: eclipse, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, serverless

Iam using the eclipse AWS toolkit. There i have the option to create a serverless project or a lambda project.
With Lambda i have already did some tests. I could create a lambda function packed in a jar file and upload it in to aws.

AFAIK lambdas are serverless. So what is the serverless project ?

Comment: Not a SO question

Comment: Mind your language. Its a forum where mainly people deal with coding. From which angle it is relevant in SO. Learn [HOW TO ASK](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Serverless projects are the one that get deployed on AWS CloudFormation and run Lambda functions in response to RESTful web requests.

Comment: I know how to ask, and i already knew someone is going to dislike... but sometimes you cant ask a better question because you need a better overview..

Comment: Have you thought to move it to Server Vault?

Comment: no i have not. What is the difference between AWS Serverless and SAM Serverless Application Model?

Comment: The goal of AWS SAM is to define a standard application model for serverless applications. SAM is a plugin/framework to export AWS SAM templates for a service.